# Who can edit questions?

Tags: discussion, support

Some dude with less than 5k reputation edited this question of mine: [Is there a definition/test for "lack of merit" (legal arguments)?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/92822/is-there-a-definition-test-for-lack-of-merit-legal-arguments)

I don't want that modification. Of course I can edit it back myself, but it seems that wouldn't prevent the dude from persisting.

Is the reputation threshold for editing arbitrary questions so low? Can the question be protected?

Comment: Is this just a complaint about the reputation threshold for edits to not require review before they take effect?  If so [Meta.SE] would be the appropriate forum because it's not unique to Law.SE.

Comment: @feetwet Maybe it can/should be made unique? The reputation histogram is not the same for every SE. I would argue that for Law.SE, the threshold should start at 10k, 5k at the very least. Then, what about protecting the question?

Comment: Moderators can protect a question in the event of an "edit war."  The best way to suggest that is via a flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The edit was clearly not matching your intent, rollback is appropriate.

[Editing is a privilege gained for **1000 Reputation**](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit). I believe no stack can have a different setting for that. Nor can we remove the "No peer review" that is granted at 2000 reputation.

> We believe in the power of community editing. That means once you've generated enough reputation, we trust you to edit *anything* in the system without it going through peer review. Not just your posts — *anyone's* posts!

Of course, with great power comes great responsibility. At times users misuse their power, or unintentionally deviate from the intention of the original author, and then rollback is in order. Possibly even a flag to establish a rep-sheet of the violator.

#### Further reading:

- [Misusing edit options for users with reputation of 2000+](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203954/misusing-edit-options-for-users-with-reputation-of-2000)